# Controls and loop not working on Youtube video (YouTube API)

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api

I'm using YouTube's API to load a YouTube video on my page. I have `'controls': 0` and `'loop': 1` but the video title still shows and it doesn't loop once the video is complete. Unsure why?

**Code**:

```js
    //  Load  IFrame Player API 
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // Creating iframe
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        videoId: 'jagIsKF8oVA',        
        playerVars: {'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0, 'mute' : 1, 'loop': 1, 'rel': 0 },
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
      });
    }

    //  Calls function
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
      event.target.playVideo();
    }

    var done = false;
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      // if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      //   setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      //   done = true;
      // }
    }
    function stopVideo() {
      // player.stopVideo();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based from your problem, you can't use the `controls` parameter to hide the title of the video. 
From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters),

> **controls**
>
> This parameter indicates whether the **video player controls** are
>   displayed:
>
> - controls=0 – Player controls do not display in the player.
> - controls=1 (default) – Player controls display in the player.

and for `loop` parameter:

> loop
>
> **Note**: This parameter has limited support in the AS3 player and in IFrame embeds, which could load either the AS3 or HTML5 player.
>   Currently, the loop parameter only works in the AS3 player when used
>   in conjunction with the playlist parameter. To loop a single video,
>   set the loop parameter value to 1 and set the playlist parameter value
>   to the same video ID already specified in the Player API URL:
>
> ```
>  https://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?
>      version=3
>      &loop=1
>      &playlist=VIDEO_ID
> ```

To display information like title, you can use the `showinfo` parameter:

> showinfo
>
> Supported values are 0 and 1.
>
> Setting the parameter's value to 0 causes the player to not display
>   information like the video title and uploader before the video starts
>   playing.
>
> If the player is loading a playlist, and you explicitly set the
>   parameter value to 1, then, upon loading, the player will also display
>   thumbnail images for the videos in the playlist.
>
> **Note**: Note: This parameter is deprecated and will be ignored after
>   September 25, 2018.

Even if it says that `showinfo` was deprecated yesterday, I have still tried if it is still working. And yes, it's still working.

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: 'jagIsKF8oVA',        
    playerVars: {'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0, 'mute' : 1, 'loop': 1, 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0 },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
```

If this will not work, I think you need to customize your code to hide the video title and use AS3 player to implement the `loop` parameter.